# VBA MS Project Loop through outlinechildren recursively

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a multilevel task hierarchy in an MPP from which I need to extract task.name for all tasks, but not including Summary Tasks in the hierarchy.

Is there an elegant and robust way to use a Do While Loop in combination with the OutlineChildren property of all summary tasks to loop through all tasks on all levels ***recursively*** in that hierarchy?

Thanks!

Edit: Perhaps a Do Until Loop is the best?

Comment: Elegant with Do/While I don't think so, but with recursive functions, probably!

Comment: What have you tries so far? share you code attmept

Comment: I don't have a code attempt yet... At the moment I am trying to write a recursive code that is not based on the do until loop.

Comment: Recursion is typically used to aggregate values to the summary level (e.g. so the summary task field value is the sum of the underlying number field). What is the output you need? If you just need a list of task names without Summary tasks, simply loop through the tasks, skipping ones with task.Summary = True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late response but I had the same question. Fortunately, I was able to find a solution [here](http://zo-d.com/blog/archives/programming/recursion-in-project-vba.html).

I have modified the code slightly but this is what I used in my own project:

```
Public Sub GetAllSubtasks(ByRef t As Task)
    Dim subtask As Task
    Debug.Print t.Name
    For Each subtask In t.OutlineChildren
        GetAllSubtasks subtask
    Next subtask
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: This solution uses recursion instead of a Do/While loop.